# Pagination, left indent

Tags: sectioning, indentation

I have created my personal style `.sty`, where I inserted all the declarations of my LaTeX document. In particular, I redefined `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection`, ..., so they appear as in the picture below )

[image]

My problem is as follows. I'd like a left indentation inside the chapter's content. Ad you can see in the picture (word processor), the title has a 0 indentation (margin set with the `geometry` package). I wish to have an indentation in all the paragraphs, section title, subsection, ..., inside the chapter, but mantaining the correct margin in the footer (see picture below).

[image]

I have obtained these one....the problem is the absence of indentation :(
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also, there was no picture in the post. You can upload the picture and remove the `!` before the `[]`. Somebody with enough reputation can then put the `!` back later.

Comment: I have added the details....and what I obtained with latex...

Comment: `\usepackage{indentfirst}` should do. Have a look at the ["Breve guida"](http://profs.scienze.univr.it/~gregorio/breveguida.pdf)

Comment: all the body should be indented....

Comment: @DavideMaggiulli No, it's the chapter title that's outdented. It makes a big difference, doesn't it? :)

Comment: @egreg: As Barbara said below the footnotes and header/footer are outdented too …

Answer (score 1):

I guess it could be easier to define the body margin with `gemotry` and shift the head line into the margin, like this

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    left=5cm,
}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\LARGE}{\hspace*{-2cm}\thechapter}{2em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{-2cm}{3\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}

\usepackage{lipsum}% blind text

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\lipsum[2-3]
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: but this doesn't keep the left edge of the footer at the same horizontal position as that of the headings, and that is what was requested.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I know O:-) but it seems easier to shift some elements (chapter heading and foot(notes)) into the margin than changing the margin for normal text … my answer should be a first approach on this …